# SwiftUI app crashes while scrolling section in List via ScrollViewReader

Tags: ios, swiftui

In our SwiftUI application , we are using SwiftUI List in one of our screen to show list of records.

We have a requirement to scroll to specific section header once the data is fetched from API. Screen need to reload with new data and scroll to Specific section I.e Today's section.

Below code works fine till iOS16 and from iOS16 onwards we are getting the app crash.

Can anyone suggest me any probable solution to achive this ?.

struct ContentView: View {

```
@StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

var body: some View {

    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        List {
            ForEach(Array(viewModel.newSections), id: \.self) { sectionName in
                Section(header: VStack { LeaguesScheduleListSectionView(text: sectionName) }) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.newRowsPerSection[sectionName] ?? []) { leagueScheduleEvent in
                        LeaguesScheduleListRowView(leagueSchedule: leagueScheduleEvent)

                    }
                }
                .id(sectionName)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)

        .onAppear(perform: {
             if viewModel.newSections.contains("Today/Ongoing"),
             viewModel.newRowsPerSection[("Today/Ongoing")]?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
             proxy.scrollTo("Today/Ongoing", anchor: UnitPoint.topLeading)
             }
        })
    }
```

}

The same code works fine without any issue if we replace List with LazyVStack.

Can some one shed some lights to resolve the crash here.

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: @Paulw11 Here is the crash received while opening the screen

2023-03-10 23:58:32.773767+0530 Tenmates-Staging-[33244:3522823] *** Assertion failure in -[SwiftUI.UpdateCoalescingCollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:], UICollectionView.m:7349

layer = <CALayer: 0x600000483960>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {393, 1344}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x13c197d60>; dataSource: <_TtGC7SwiftUI31UICollectionViewListCoordinatorGVS_28CollectionViewListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___: 0x13c18f130>>.'

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb Updated the description of the issue with more details